# Cannot obtain provider factory for data provider named MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2012, dataset

I have Windows 8.1, MySql 5.6, and Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

I am trying to set a DataSet, but I am having the error `Cannot obtain provider factory for data provider named MySql.Data.MySqlClient` when I try to drag a table to the DataSet.

a) The Server Explorer can access the database and show me all tables, and the "Test Connection" button returns a successful message.

b) I added MySql references to the bin folder (`MySql.Data`, `MySql.Data.Entity`, `MySql.Web`).

c) I edited the `Web.config` file removing `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` invariant and adding it again with "correct" settings. I tried to set `<connectionStrings>`, `<DbProviderFactories>`, membership providers, profile providers, and RoleManager providers;

d) I have already uninstalled and reinstalled MySql and Visual Studio.

Nothing seems to work, and the same error remains happening. I have already tried a lot of suggestions from this and other forums.

Answer (score 6):

Worked for me, steps below:

- Close Visual Studio
- Run the MySQL Connector/Net and remove your installation
- Run the Connector again and install as you have done prior to deletion(typical/custom).
- Open Visual studio
- Delete all connections to server/database/dataset from the solution and server explorer. Do not remove any lines of code.
- Re-establish a connection to your database,naming it as it was.
- Re-establish a connection to your data source for data set as it was.
- Click play, be happy!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, closing VS (2017 in my case), reinstalling the latest version of connector (https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) solved the very same issue for me.
(just as usual... Windows issue? reboot -> reinstall -> profit)

Answer (score 3):

you have to install mysql connector
just download the last version of MySql connector and install it while closing visual studio

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have installed "Connector/NET" and "MySQL for Visual Studio". Run "MySQL Installer" and install those two.

Comment: Unfortunately I have the same problem. I've done that things and its still not working.

Answer (score 0):

C4U gave me the clue I needed after fighting with this all day.  Connector/Net seemed to install with MySQL for Visual Studio when I used the installer the first time.  I could create a connection in the Server Explorer but couldn't create a new connection from within my project.  I also couldn't run the little blue button (MySQL Website Configuration). I tried rerunning the installer and couldn't find Connector/Net.  It had not installed completely.
What worked:
I closed Visual Studio and opened Programs and Features from the Control panel and uninstalled ALL MySql Connector programs, including Connector/Net.  Then I reran the same MySql Visual Studio Installer I had run before and, voila!, I could see the Connector/Net and install it.  Then I opened Visual Studio, deleted my connections, and clicked on the little blue button (MySQL Website Configuration).  Worked!  I could also create a connection inside my project.
AND I didn't have to add ANY reference or ANYTHING to the config file.